# copy node xml to another xml

Tags: xml, dom

I would like to copy a node of a xml to another xml.
I have created the two DOM of the xml and when i find the node i need i try this code

```
NodeList elementi = doc.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < elementi.getLength(); i++){
    NodeList datiTitolo = elementi.item(i).getChildNodes();
    for (int j = 0; j < datiTitolo.getLength(); j++){
        if(datiTitolo.item(j).getFirstChild().getTextContent().equals("cariplo")){
            buy.importNode(datiTitolo.item(j), true);
            System.out.println("Fatto");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

but seems to do nothing.. when i write into the file nothing appaer
where is the error?

Comment: What language? Java? Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually insert the imported Node into the target document.

```
Node node = buy.importNode(datiTitolo.item(j), true);
buy.appendChild(node); // or wherever else the imported Node should be inserted
```